# What's wrong with const?

Tags: c++, c++11

What are the known shortfalls of `const` in C++ and C++0x?

Comment: I think they're useful because make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Need to state a question before you'll get your answer, methinks

Comment: The only problem I see with `const` is that its readiness and *undertandiness* varies widely depending on the level of the C++ programmer, (some confusion about to which element `const` does apply in a complex declaration, for instance). Besides it is part of the language, and should be used - as long as the book from B.Stroustrup has been read :-)

Comment: @Vilx don't you think that "while(x < ThingsToDo)" has much more sense than "while(x < 314145.315)"??

Comment: Interesting to see how many times this question gets closed and reopened.

Comment: @David: Looks like a question to me.

Comment: voted to reopen. helpful question definitely. pity we can't make it community wiki. it's definitely not a non-cw question. iirc, one base rule is: if by nature it can't have an "accepted answer", it should be cw.

Comment: @Tomalak it's more of a question now that it has been edited!

Comment: @David: I see no edit. Perhaps it was too quick.

Comment: @Tomalak: It was edited about thirty seconds after being put up. I frankly find the response to this question hilarious, as there's an exactly identical question about ADL that nobody wants to vote to close.

Comment: @DeadMG I don't understand the vote-to-close either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two main issues that I have seen frequent complaints about in newsgroups, are

- The need to waste a lot of time on supporting non-const-aware APIs (especially Microsoft's).
- The [need to define both const and non-const version of a method](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12).

I think the latter could/should be supported by the language.

Possibly in conjunction with support for covariant member function implementations, because both need some way to pick up the type of the `this` pointer.

A third issue is that

- [const does not propagate to owned objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#const_and_immutable_in_D).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Which Microsoft APIs are not-const-aware? IIRC the Windows API uses LPCTSTRs, MFC uses const correctly IIRC, etc. I can't think of any.

Comment: @Rup: would need a lot of research going through them all. i'm reporting what people have complained about, but i can confirm from own experience. if there were just a few problematic functions then perhaps i'd remember names, but it's all over.

Comment: @Rup: Many Microsoft APIs don't use a lot of const. When was the last time you saw a const HANDLE? Or a const IDirect3DDevice9*? Microsoft uses const for strings and that's about it.

Comment: @DeadMG: A `HANDLE` is an opaque object that you cannot modify anyway without using API functions. For the COM interfaces they use attributes like `[in]` and `[out]`. And for most other C types, they do use `const`.

Comment: Perhaps it's not purely Win32 but COM's `BSTR` can't be a `const` (since it's a `typedef` which doesn't allow putting the `const` on the correct part of the type).

Comment: @Philipp: You can modify the `HANDLE` just fine; you can't easily modify the thing that it ends up pointing to. `HANDLE` being `const` would help to avoid people forgetting that.

Comment: +1 for "The need to define both const and non-const version of a method." !

Comment: @litb Ah I missed that on my first read. +1 from me too for that.

Comment: @Tomalak note that "@name" will notify the user only if replace(<name's nick>, " ", "") starts with "name". So "@Joh" would notify me of your comment and "@JohannesSchaub" would too. But "@litb" won't :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: Maybe I was hiding :P (OK)

Comment: What do you mean by const not propagating to owned objects? If you hold a constant reference to any structure, all members are also considered constant. You even have the keyword `mutable` to allow implementation of caches (i.e. it doesn't impact the output if this variable changes).

Comment: @PierreBdR:  I think what they mean is that a member `int *` is seen as `int * const` (and not `int const *`) from within a const member function.  As a result what it points to can still be changed.

Comment: @Alf: Can you add some links relating to the "need to add both const and non const versions"?

Comment: @Richard: the **[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12)** is a good starting point. I did a little googling and discovered that many other resources are outdated, including a GOTW by Herb Sutter, linked to from **[the Wikipedia page on const correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#const_and_immutable_in_D)**. Herb's **[GOTW](http://gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm)** advises "When using return-by-value for non-builtin return types, prefer returning a const value", reasonable in its day, but which with Mojo or C++0x prevents efficient "moving".

Answer (score 58):

The only thing wrong with `const` is that it is ***seriously underrated*** by to many developers. It's one of the best tools in C++'s toolbox, very sharp, and yet not dangerous to cut yourself with.

Comment: "But what made those who had laughed at me stop laughing was when, after several days, it became obvious that some several very hard to reproduce bugs which a few of my coworkers were desperately looking for had disappeared." (from [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/254713#254713))

Answer (score 50):

The main problem is that you have to write it. It should be the default, and all mutable variables or parameters should be specified explicitly.

Comment: Can’t upvote this enough. Even though (or because) it would wreak havoc with most programmers’ preconceptions.

Comment: Except for two things: The majority of variables are created to be written to. Having them all read only by default creates more work. Also the C and C++ language philosophy is that the programmer knows what they're doing and the language shouldn't prevent you from doing what ever you want.

Comment: @Jay “The majority of variables are created to be written to.” – *Once*. Rarely do I change the value of a variable after its first assignment (containers are kind of an exception).

Comment: You're never going to find that one way or the other is better. Some objects you create for reading/writing (loop counters, iterators, containers, streams, most strings) and others you only assign to once -- actually, I can't think of any examples for that one. Why are your one-time writes not constant initialisations?

Comment: wow, i totally missed your answer when i wrote my own (now deleted, was saying the same). One reason I deleted mine is that I can't imagine it's a sane default for local variables. But I definitely can imagine it's sane for by-value parameters. So maybe making parameters const by default, unless you put the "mutable" keyword?

Comment: Many class member variables are initialised only in the constructor and then never change in the lifetime of the class. I have actually sometimes changed my policy to make these const and public, rather than non-const, private with public getters. I know many people don't like the concept of public members and if they are non-const I agree but if they are I don't see the issue.

Comment: @Joh: I usually have `const` local variables, too. Of course, the issue there is much smaller: it doesn't help with regard to const-correctness, but it helps finding errors.

Comment: @Philipp: Phew, I'm glad I'm not the only one making local variables `const`. `:)`

Comment: -1 from me I'm afraid.  As litb suggests it would be a sensible default for function parameters, but it's rare for me to need a local variable whose value remains fixed after its initial assignment.  C++ is an imperative language; there's no shame in assigning twice :)

Comment: @j_random: C++ is a multi-paradigm language and, for example, increasingly supports functional programming. I find myself rely on mutable data less and less over the years, and make everything `const` by default.

Answer (score 18):

What's wrong with `const` is that many programmers don't seem to be able to understand it completely, and a "half-const-correct" project simply does not work. This is what you need to know:

1. `Foo` vs. `const Foo` (or `Foo const`)
2. `Foo&` vs. `const Foo&` (or `Foo const&`)

   - references-to-const bind to all kinds of things, while references-to-non-const don't
3. `Foo*` vs. `const Foo*` (or `Foo const*`)

   - pointer variables can also be `Foo* const` and `const Foo* const` (or `Foo const* const`)
4. `void Foo::mutator()` vs. `int Foo::accessor() const`

   - but pointer members inside const member functions still point to non-const objects
   - so we can accidentally return non-const data from a const-function
5. `iterator` vs. `const_iterator`

   - iterator variables can also be `const iterator` and `const const_iterator`

Migrating to C++ from a language that has no const concept is quite hard, any many fail to see the point.

Comment: Nit-picking: references to objects can't be const, but references can reference const objects. (Most people know what you mean, but the distinction is more important with pointers, where we have both const pointers and pointers to const.)

Comment: @Phil: Right, I changed the relevant parts from English to C++ ;-)

Comment: That many programmers don't understand it is not a problem with `const`. It's a problem with the programmers, and the seriously pathetic state of programming education across the Western world.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to use const. I already know how to use const. The question relates to the downsides of const.

Comment: Good breakdown of the uses of const Fred, but where can I find a good reference on the given use cases ? I am new to the idea that const can save a lot of bugs, but I need a thorough understanding of it prior to use. Hope someone can help with a good tutorial/links

Comment: @OverTheEdge I suggest you buy "Effective C++" (3rd Edition) by Scott Meyers. Item 3 devotes 10 pages to the topic.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with const is the programmers that use it incorrectly our inconsistently

Answer (score 3):

One thing that is "wrong" is that you cannot convert T** to T const * const * which should be allowed because it is not dangerous. Not allowing T** to convert to T const ** is correct, that conversion is not valid.

I have sometimes mentioned that const actually is a cheap way to "split" your interface into read-only methods and write methods. It would probably be impractical in C++. It would be more practical in Java to have ReadOnly versions of collections though, where they don't have const and where their collection types are more object-orientated.

const-ness does not propagate: The issue here is that if I pImpl my class, the constness is not "checked" by the compiler, i.e. my interface class can have a "const" method call a non-const method on the pImpl and the compiler won't complain. That is because the only thing my const method is guaranteed not to do is change the pointer to point to a different object, and my pImpl is never going to change. It could even be a const pointer (not pointer to const).

The lack of proper co-variance between `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<const T>` might be an issue too, although in general I have seen that not to be the problem, but that developers usually typedef their shared_ptrs and rarely typedef the shared_ptr to const. And they will sometimes pass `const shared_ptr<T> &` and think that they are passing a shared pointer to a const T (as with const T*) which they are not.

Comment: "cannot convert `T**` to `T const * const *`" - this part is wrong (at least with the compilers i use); i recall it was an annoyance in C but C++ got it right.

Comment: you can have const-checking for pimpl class, no big deal ... for example look at Qts use of pimpl classes.. (they use 2 private pimpl-accessor functions (const/nonconst) for accessing the pimpl object, if you want to make sure you dont access the pimpl object without using these functions (und thus circumventing the const-check), you can use a fully opaque `void*` for the pimpl object, and add some reinterpret_casts to the acessor functions (look at the implemtation of i.e. Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE)

Comment: @anatolyg: You are correct. The first paragraph doesn't describe something "wrong" with `const` because it's not true. See 4.4 [conv.qual] / 4 of ISO/IEC 14882:2003.

Answer (score 1):

"issues"?

If you aren't going to be modifying the value of a passed pointer (it is used purely for pass-by-reference input to a function), mark it is `const`.  Ditto if the value of a particular variable will not change after its initialization.  If a function is safe to call on a `const` class instance, mark it `const` too.  The more items are correctly annotated `const`, the less likely you are to inadvertently make a mistake and the more optimizations the compiler will be theoretically able to perform in the absence of complete knowledge (such as when compiling with only function prototypes available).

Modern versions of gcc have support for warning when you try to cast a `const` variable to a non-`const` one.  I suggest you leave those warnings enabled.

The only thing to watch out for is exactly *what* you are marking `const`; `const char * foo()` is not the same as `char * foo() const`.

Comment: I'm not asking how to use const. I already know how to use const. I was looking for *problems* with const.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that has not been mentioned yet is the possibility for a badly designed interface to subvert const (even in the absence of casts).

Example:

```
class TreeNode {
public:
    TreeNode& getParent() const { return *parent_; }
    TreeNode& getLeft()   const { return *left_;   }
    TreeNode& getRight()  const { return *right_;  }
private:
    //TreeNode has a pointer to the Tree to enable navigation of the tree.
    //Assume that other design constraints mean that this must be a pointer 
    //rather than a reference.
    TreeNode* parent_;
    TreeNode* left_;
    TreeNode* right_;
};
//This function demonstrates the ability for const to be subverted.
TreeNode& remove_const(TreeNode const& toRemoveConstFrom) {
    TreeNode& parent(toRemoveConstFrom.getParent());
    TreeNode& leftChild(parent.getLeft());
    TreeNode& rightChild(parent.getRight());
    return &toRemoveConstFrom == &leftChild ? leftChild : rightChild;
}
```

The intransitive nature of const means that it is possible to have an interface where a non-const reference to an object can be obtained from a const reference to an object. This is something to be careful of when designing interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers below state things such as "what is wrong with `const` is that X people do Y". Those are not answers but *symptoms*. Those are not things wrong with `const`. There's *barely* any wrong thing with `const`...  **Those are things wrong with people who can't RTFM**.

Answer (score 0):

`const` is great. `const` is important. `const`-correctness is necessary condition for an API to be good.

Yet there are two issue I've had with `const`, repeatedly.

- There's no way to mark a variable as `const` retroactively. You must either declare a variable code, in which case you *have* to initialize it immediatly. What if the initialization code contains an `if`, though? You have the choice of either omitting the `const` (undesirably), using operator `?` instead of `if` (harms readability). Java get's that right, BTW - `const` variables don't have to be initialized right away, they just have to be initialized *before* they're first read, and they have to be initialized in *all* branches of an `if`.
- There's no way to specifiy that an object passed by reference to a function won't change for the duration of the function call. `const T& t` does *not* mean that the object pointed to by `t` won't change, but only that the reference `t` cannot be used to change it. The compiller still has to assume that any function call which it does not see into *might* change the object. It some cases, that prevents quite a few optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

One problem is that the language also lets you const_cast it away, which defeats the purpose of using const in the first place.

Comment: not really as you can only explictly cast it away and you obviously need to be able to const_cast to support legacy APIs

Comment: Not this again... `const` would be useless **without** the ability to cast it away, because in real world code, you have to deal with APIs written by programmers who don't understand const correctness (or way back in a time were `const` wasn't part of C++ yet).

Comment: @FredOverflow I see... I hadn't ever run into that situation before.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @jk the problem I have run into is when I have a const function and another developer const_casts it away, which defeated the whole point of making it const in the first place.  At least that is my recollection.

Comment: @FredOverflow: but maybe it would be a good thing if those programmers were hunted down and killed by people who can no longer work around their broken code by const-casting? ;-) Regarding ancient code - something can still be a shortfall of the language even if the motivation for the shortfall is to support pre-standard code and/or conventions. For instance you might think that the automatic conversion to `void*` is a shortfall of C++: it's needed for e.g. `std::memcpy`, but in the context of C++, functions shouldn't be designed to silently accept any pointer regardless of type-safety.

Comment: @Dave: *Why* did the developer cast it away? Most casts are evil and/or unnecessary. If you don't trust programmers, C++ is the wrong language.

Comment: @FredOverflow it was out of necessity to get a particular behavior that he wanted, but at the expense of everything else.  The change never made it through, though.  :)

Comment: @Steve: How would killing them *now* solve the problem? Let the damn terminators do the job thoroughly and wipe the non-believers from history!

Comment: No, although `const_cast` is legal, writing to an object-created-as-`const` (even if you've casted away the constness on the _variable_) is not legal.

Comment: (That said, sure, it would be nice if `const_cast` didn't even exist. It's a hack and can easily lead to the illegality I describe above.)

Answer (score -2):

One thing is that it is still possible subvert it.  i.e. it is still legal to do something like this:

```
void foo(const inst& x)
{
   const_cast<int&> x = 3;
}
```

You can even use things like `memset` to subvert it without an explicit `const_cast`.

This is a trade-off between having the compiler enforce `const` and allowing some flexibility for non `const` aware interfaces.

Which leads to another limitation, in that it has not been universally embraced, which is in part due to another problem, which is that using `const` is an all-or-nothing proposition.  If you start using it, you will need to propagate it throughout your code base.

Comment: No, this is possibly Undefined Behaviour (if the original object was created `const`) and in the context of this function must be assumed to be. A `const_cast` is legal, but writing to an object created as `const`, whether you've casted away the constness or not, is illegal.

Comment: Well, yes, but if you think as const in terms of a contract or promise that I won't change it (even if it was non-const before), then it is possible to break it.

Comment: But you can make promises in form of comments in every language and then subvert them. `const` however is a non-comment/builtin tool that forces you to not break the contract _by default_, whereas in non-const-correct languages you may accidentally change something documented as invariant.